# How to check if MMDevice is captured exclusively?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, audio, windows-core-audio

I am able to capture default microphone exclusively using similar code as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/exclusive-mode-streams

I also need to check if an audio device is already captured exclusively by some app.
As a possible solution I tried to catpure audio device in shared mode and if it is already caputred exclusively I am getting this error: AUDCLNT_E_DEVICE_IN_USE

This seems to work but I am wondering if we can check if device is captured exclusively, without capturing it, maybe by reading some propery of the audio device.

Comment: Why is the shared method a problem?

Comment: No problem. Just asked to check if there is no better way.

Comment: *"I am wondering if we can check if device is captured exclusively, without capturing it"* - What you're really asking here is: "How do I implement a [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race?" The answer to that question is: Don't. If you need exclusive access to a device, request exclusive access and handle the error case.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you could try to use [IAudioSessionEvents::OnSessionDisconnected method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nf-audiopolicy-iaudiosessionevents-onsessiondisconnected#parameters)

`DisconnectReasonExclusiveModeOverride`:The (shared-mode) audio session was disconnected to make the audio endpoint device available for an exclusive-mode connection.

Comment: @Ashot If you have got any chance to check my answer?If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.